# Extract id and name from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have some results from a db query using the with, I then convert it to an array because I want to extract just the id and the name.

I tried used the array_only method like
http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#arrays

```
$result = array_only($result, ['id', 'user.name']);
```

which gave me nothing, so I don't think it supports dot notation.

I am expecting to get

```
array
    array
       id => 1
       name => Bill Cstevens
    array
       id => 2
       name => Jennyfer Aufderhar
    array
       id => 3
       name => Catharine Kuhlman
```

here is my array I am doing. I thought there was some sort of helper, without me having to write some code to loop this myself.

I also tried to do $queryResult->lists('user.name', 'id'); since lists is supported on Collections - which did give me the id but the user.name was null :(

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '1'
      'user_id' => string '3'
      'phone' => string '04 346 6337'
      'address' => string '819 Quigley Grove, Jazmynston, 6786'
      'created_at' => string '2014-06-12 19:27:00'
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-15 05:57:04'
      'user' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '3'
          'name' => string 'Bill Cstevens'
          'email' => string 'xxxx@example.com'
          'created_at' => string '2014-06-15 22:40:25'
          'updated_at' => string '2014-07-02 06:35:03'
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '2'
      'user_id' => string '6'
      'phone' => string '06 354 5069'
      'address' => string '7 Bergnaum Mall, Stuartston, '
      'created_at' => string '2014-06-15 22:40:25'
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-02 06:35:03'
      'user' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '6'
          'name' => string 'Jennyfer Aufderhar'
          'email' => string 'rudy.baumbach@example.com'
          'created_at' => string '2014-06-15 22:40:25'
          'updated_at' => string '2014-07-02 06:35:03'
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '3'
      'user_id' => string '7'
      'phone' => string '04 777 9959'
      'address' => string '4 O'Kon Drive, Janville, Hawkes Bay, 1667'
      'created_at' => string '2014-05-31 17:49:09'
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-12 21:46:06'
      'user' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '5'
          'name' => string 'Catharine Kuhlman'
          'email' => string 'dimitri50@example.com'
          'created_at' => string '2014-05-31 17:49:09'
          'updated_at' => string '2014-07-12 21:46:06'
```

Comment: [Short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96) is only supported from PHP 5.4, have you tried it with traditional notation e.g. `array('id', 'user.name')` to make sure it's not that? Just a thought...

Comment: I think this still is an open question, because I am also looking for similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just combine two of the helper functions:

```
array_only(array_dot($result), ['id', 'user.name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when it's converted to array_dot then I get 0.id, 0.user.name etc, so I can't then use array_only...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L328-L331) on the collection:

```
$addresses = $collection->map(function ($address)
{
    return ['id' => $address->id, 'name' => $address->user->name];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What Dave mentioned or you can use array_get using dot notation which will retrieve nested array as per documentation like this -

```
$array = array('names' => array('joe' => array('programmer')));
$value = array_get($array, 'names.joe');
```

Refer to http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#arrays

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work with the array I have, I have to specify 0.user.name not just user.name